# Animation in Launch Screen in xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to animate a set of images in my Launch Screen, but I do not know how. I have seen some tutorials telling me to put code in the App Delegate (DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions) and nothing has worked.

Could someone help me animate my Launch Screen?

Comment: You cannot animate your launch screen. All you can do is display an animation as a splash screen after tha app has finished launching.

Answer (score 1):

I am supposing that you do quite a bit of work on launch, and you do not want your user to stare at a static image while this work is going on. What you need to do is do the work in the background (using gcd). This way, the launch screen will be gone quickly. However, you are not ready of course: hence your need for animations. So what I do is add my own equivalent of the start screen on top of my first visible UIView, do my animations and then tear down my start up screen. If you want to see what I do in action, try it out with my App (The Opera Player)